# d3 force directed graph using node names for links

Tags: json, d3.js

D3.js force directed graph need json data in the format

```
{
  "nodes" : [{"name" : "User Login"},
             {"name" : "Appointments"},
             {"name" : "Store Visit"},
             {"name" : "Visit History"},
             {"name" : "Resume Store Visit"}],

 "links" : [{"source" : 1, "target" : 0, "value" : 1},
            {"source" : 2, "target" : 0, "value" : 8},
            {"source" : 3, "target" : 0, "value" : 10},
            {"source" : 3, "target" : 2, "value" : 6},
            {"source" : 4, "target" : 0, "value" : 1}]
};
```

is there a way to specify links source and target value as node names rather indexes?

Please note that I am trying to render the graph based on links json like
links: [{node1, node2},
        { node1, node3}]; instead of specifying indexes etc.

Comment: Can you explain please how the question I've marked this a duplicate of doesn't address what you want to do? As far as I can see it's exactly the same thing except that you don't have an explicit ID field.

Comment: i am sorry as i thought the solution provided is not correct so i believed it is not duplicate.

Comment: How is it not correct?

Comment: as i said i misinterpreted the code

Comment: Oh ok I see. All good then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use array map function.

```
var graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "User Login"
  }, {
    "name": "Appointments"
  }, {
    "name": "Store Visit"
  }, {
    "name": "Visit History"
  }, {
    "name": "Resume Store Visit"
  }],

  "links": [{
    "source": "Appointments",
    "target": "User Login",
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": "Store Visit",
    "target": "User Login",
    "value": 8
  }, {
    "source": "Visit History",
    "target": "User Login",
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "source": "Visit History",
    "target": "Store Visit",
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": "Resume Store Visit",
    "target": "User Login",
    "value": 1
  }]
};


graph.links = graph.links.map(function(l) {
    var sourceNode = graph.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.name === l.source;
    })[0],
        targetNode = graph.nodes.filter(function(n) {
            return n.name === l.target;
        })[0];

    return {
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode,
        value: l.value
    };
});
```

```js
var width = 960,
  height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .charge(-120)
  .linkDistance(30)
  .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var graph = {
  "nodes": [{
    "name": "User Login"
  }, {
    "name": "Appointments"
  }, {
    "name": "Store Visit"
  }, {
    "name": "Visit History"
  }, {
    "name": "Resume Store Visit"
  }],

  "links": [{
    "source": "Appointments",
    "target": "User Login",
    "value": 1
  }, {
    "source": "Store Visit",
    "target": "User Login",
    "value": 8
  }, {
    "source": "Visit History",
    "target": "User Login",
    "value": 10
  }, {
    "source": "Visit History",
    "target": "Store Visit",
    "value": 6
  }, {
    "source": "Resume Store Visit",
    "target": "User Login",
    "value": 1
  }]
};

graph.links = graph.links.map(function(l) {
  var sourceNode = graph.nodes.filter(function(n) {
      return n.name === l.source;
    })[0],
    targetNode = graph.nodes.filter(function(n) {
      return n.name === l.target;
    })[0];

  return {
    source: sourceNode,
    target: targetNode,
    value: l.value
  };
});

force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(graph.links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
    return Math.sqrt(d.value);
  });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.group);
  })
  .call(force.drag);

node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

force.on("tick", function() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
});
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the requirement is to be able to draw graph which has json input for links as node names.

Comment: @Vik  yes I know. I have used node names as source and target in my code sample.   `"source": "Appointments",    "target": "User Login",` etc.

Comment: @Vik added the data sample outside the snippet also.